# Nested if loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to get nested if loops straight in my head. In trying I put together this simple script

```
x<-c(1:9)
for(i in seq(along=x)) {
    if(x[i]<5){
        y<-(x*3)
    } else {
        y<-(x*5)  
    }
}
```

It calculates an answer for me without giving an error. but the answer is wrong.
So what wrong with the script

Comment: `seq(along = x)` should be `seq_along(x)`

Comment: Stop thinking R is SAS. You are making nine assignments to y. The first 4 are the length-9 vector `x*3` and the last 5 (overwriting the earlier ones) are the length-9 vector `x*5`. `y <- (x*5)` is not restricted to the [i] locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could also this in two steps in a vectorized way.

```
y <- x*5
y[x <5] <- x[x < 5] *3
y
#[1]  3  6  9 12 25 30 35 40 45
```

This should be faster than the `ifelse` or the `for` loop.

#### Benchmarks

```
x1 <- 1:1e7
system.time( ifelse(x1 < 1e4, 3 * x1, 5 * x1))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.58    0.32    0.91

system.time({ y1 <- x1*5
           y1[x1 < 1e4] <- x1[x1 < 1e4] *3})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.17    0.04    0.21
```

Comment: Your right I miss read it. Working to long, Better take a break. Sorry I apologies. R is blinding me now

Comment: @user20650  Thank you for pointing the mistake.  I updated it.